# Having problems with converting pinescript v2 into v3

Tags: pine-script

I want to convert this fragment of code from v2 to version3 or 4 in Pinescript. I try to follow some tutorials but I didn't find any information how to deal with conversion between versions

```
//@version=3

strategy(title = "Strategy_upgrade_try", shorttitle = "Symphony 1.1", overlay = false, default_qty_type = strategy.percent_of_equity, default_qty_value = 100, pyramiding = 20)

//Settings

//needlong = input(true, defval = true, title = "Long")
//needshort = input(true, defval = true, title = "Short")

capital = input(100, defval = 100, minval = 1, maxval = 10000, title = "Lot, %")
usersi1 = input(true, defval = true, title = "Use RSI 1")
rsiperiod1 = input(4, defval = 4, minval = 2, maxval = 100, title = "RSI 1 Period")
rsilimit1 = input(20, defval = 20, minval = 2, maxval = 50, title = "RSI 1 Limit")
usersi2 = input(true, defval = true, title = "Use RSI 2")
rsiperiod2 = input(7, defval = 7, minval = 2, maxval = 100, title = "RSI 2 Period")
rsilimit2 = input(25, defval = 25, minval = 2, maxval = 50, title = "RSI 2 Limit")
usersi3 = input(true, defval = true, title = "Use RSI 3")
rsiperiod3 = input(14, defval = 14, minval = 2, maxval = 100, title = "RSI 3 Period")
rsilimit3 = input(30, defval = 30, minval = 2, maxval = 50, title = "RSI 3 Limit")
usersi4 = input(false, defval = false, title = "Use RSI 4")
rsiperiod4 = input(21, defval = 21, minval = 2, maxval = 100, title = "RSI 4 Period")
rsilimit4 = input(35, defval = 35, minval = 2, maxval = 50, title = "RSI 4 Limit")
usersi5 = input(false, defval = false, title = "Use RSI 5")
rsiperiod5 = input(28, defval = 28, minval = 2, maxval = 100, title = "RSI 5 Period")
rsilimit5 = input(40, defval = 40, minval = 2, maxval = 50, title = "RSI 5 Limit")
cf = input(false, defval = false, title = "Use color filter")
fromyear = input(1900, defval = 1900, minval = 1900, maxval = 2100, title = "From Year")
toyear = input(2100, defval = 2100, minval = 1900, maxval = 2100, title = "To Year")
frommonth = input(01, defval = 01, minval = 01, maxval = 12, title = "From Month")
tomonth = input(12, defval = 12, minval = 01, maxval = 12, title = "To Month")
fromday = input(01, defval = 01, minval = 01, maxval = 31, title = "From Day")
today = input(31, defval = 31, minval = 01, maxval = 31, title = "To Day")

//RSI
rsi1 = rsi(close, rsiperiod1)
rsi2 = rsi(close, rsiperiod2)
rsi3 = rsi(close, rsiperiod3)
rsi4 = rsi(close, rsiperiod4)
rsi5 = rsi(close, rsiperiod5)

//Signals
up1 = rsi1 < rsilimit1 and usersi1  
up2 = rsi2 < rsilimit2 and usersi2
up3 = rsi3 < rsilimit3 and usersi3
up4 = rsi4 < rsilimit4 and usersi4
up5 = rsi5 < rsilimit5 and usersi5

str = up5 ? 5 : up4 ? 4 : up3 ? 3 : up2 ? 2 : up1 ? 1 : str[1]
up = up1 or up2 or up3 or up4 or up5
exit = (rsi1 > rsilimit1 and str == 1) or (rsi2 > rsilimit2 and str == 2) or (rsi3 > rsilimit3 and str == 3) or (rsi4 > rsilimit4 and str == 4) or (rsi5 > rsilimit5 and str == 5)
lot = strategy.position_size == 0 ? strategy.equity / close * capital / 100 : lot[1]

//Background
col = up ? lime : na
bgcolor(col, transp = 0)

//Trading
if up and (close < open or cf == false)
    strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long, lot, when=(time > timestamp(fromyear, frommonth, fromday, 00, 00) and time < timestamp(toyear, tomonth, today, 23, 59)))
 
if time > timestamp(toyear, tomonth, today, 23, 59) or exit
    strategy.close_all()
```

In console I am getting:

```
Processing script...
line 48: Undeclared identifier `str`;
line 50: Undeclared identifier `str`;
line 51: Undeclared identifier `lot`;
```

I am totally new to this, I will appreciate any help.

Comment: Please edit your question and post your entire script. Including the rsiperiod inputs.

Comment: @BjornMistiaen I added the entire script to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've converted it to version 4.
Problem was that you were trying to use a historical value `[1]` on `str` and `lot` that did not exist yet. So you have to define them first, like this:

```
var int     str = na
var float   lot = na
```

Then you need to assign a value to them with `:=` instead of `=`

Also, I've removed the `defval` sections of your `input` functions, because the first parameter is already the `defval`. No need to define `defval` twice, because the compiler sees that as an error.

This will work:

```
//@version=4

strategy(title = "Strategy_upgrade_try", shorttitle = "Symphony 1.1", overlay = false, default_qty_type = strategy.percent_of_equity, default_qty_value = 100, pyramiding = 20)

//Settings

//needlong = input(true, defval = true, title = "Long")
//needshort = input(true, defval = true, title = "Short")

capital     = input(100, minval = 1, maxval = 10000, title = "Lot, %")
usersi1     = input(true, title = "Use RSI 1")
rsiperiod1  = input(4, minval = 2, maxval = 100, title = "RSI 1 Period")
rsilimit1   = input(20, minval = 2, maxval = 50, title = "RSI 1 Limit")
usersi2     = input(true, title = "Use RSI 2")
rsiperiod2  = input(7, minval = 2, maxval = 100, title = "RSI 2 Period")
rsilimit2   = input(25, minval = 2, maxval = 50, title = "RSI 2 Limit")
usersi3     = input(true, title = "Use RSI 3")
rsiperiod3  = input(14, minval = 2, maxval = 100, title = "RSI 3 Period")
rsilimit3   = input(30, minval = 2, maxval = 50, title = "RSI 3 Limit")
usersi4     = input(false, title = "Use RSI 4")
rsiperiod4  = input(21, minval = 2, maxval = 100, title = "RSI 4 Period")
rsilimit4   = input(35, minval = 2, maxval = 50, title = "RSI 4 Limit")
usersi5     = input(false, title = "Use RSI 5")
rsiperiod5  = input(28, minval = 2, maxval = 100, title = "RSI 5 Period")
rsilimit5   = input(40, minval = 2, maxval = 50, title = "RSI 5 Limit")
cf          = input(false, title = "Use color filter")
fromyear    = input(1900, minval = 1900, maxval = 2100, title = "From Year")
toyear      = input(2100, minval = 1900, maxval = 2100, title = "To Year")
frommonth   = input(01, minval = 01, maxval = 12, title = "From Month")
tomonth     = input(12, minval = 01, maxval = 12, title = "To Month")
fromday     = input(01, minval = 01, maxval = 31, title = "From Day")
today       = input(31, minval = 01, maxval = 31, title = "To Day")

var int     str = na
var float   lot = na

//RSI
rsi1 = rsi(close, rsiperiod1)
rsi2 = rsi(close, rsiperiod2)
rsi3 = rsi(close, rsiperiod3)
rsi4 = rsi(close, rsiperiod4)
rsi5 = rsi(close, rsiperiod5)

//Signals
up1 = rsi1 < rsilimit1 and usersi1  
up2 = rsi2 < rsilimit2 and usersi2
up3 = rsi3 < rsilimit3 and usersi3
up4 = rsi4 < rsilimit4 and usersi4
up5 = rsi5 < rsilimit5 and usersi5

str     := up5 ? 5 : up4 ? 4 : up3 ? 3 : up2 ? 2 : up1 ? 1 : str[1]
up      = up1 or up2 or up3 or up4 or up5
exit    = (rsi1 > rsilimit1 and str == 1) or (rsi2 > rsilimit2 and str == 2) or (rsi3 > rsilimit3 and str == 3) or (rsi4 > rsilimit4 and str == 4) or (rsi5 > rsilimit5 and str == 5)
lot     := strategy.position_size == 0 ? strategy.equity / close * capital / 100 : lot[1]

//Background
col = up ? color.lime : na
bgcolor(col, transp = 0)

//Trading
if up and (close < open or cf == false)
    strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long, lot, when=(time > timestamp(fromyear, frommonth, fromday, 00, 00) and time < timestamp(toyear, tomonth, today, 23, 59)))
 
if time > timestamp(toyear, tomonth, today, 23, 59) or exit
    strategy.close_all()
```